# Vaio E series Laptop: What Vaio 'bloat' can I remove?

Tags: uninstall

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Laptop de-crappifying](https://superuser.com/questions/98507/laptop-de-crappifying)

There's so much bloat and extras installed, and I just want a clean install. I've got REVO but I'm hesitating over what stuff I can remove without it crashing on me, or losing Internet connection...

Links, ideas, experience always appreciated

Thanks
Mike

Comment: Nice question, +1. I have a CW series Vaio and had the same question in my mind for a while.

Comment: Can you mention what extras are installed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the **[PC Decrapifier](http://www.pcdecrapifier.com/)** to remove pre-installed bloatware.

Comment: I'm going to have a look at that one. It seems quite a serious piece of software...